# Peer to peer: Ports on a windows machine

Tags: port, p2p

I'm building a peer to peer network on my machine where nodes will be listening to different ports.

I know on a windows machine ports above 1024 are available but exactly how many ports above 1024 are available?

Answer (score 0):

Port number is represented by short data type so it is ought  to be [image]

so ports are available up to 65535.